# Flixable Div Height and Width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `div` and i want it to be full screen and when minimize i need the scroll for the `div` it self show and the body overview will always be hidden , so what i need is to make this `div` full screen on high screens resolution and in low resolution the scroll of the `div` not the body show(`overflow-x` and `overflow-y`)

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say... I also don't see any relation to Java.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java (even if you are writing JSP or servlets, it is all about the HTML/CSS).

Comment: i need my div to be full screen on high screen resolution like 1280*800 and in low screen resolution like 800*1200 the scroll of the div show i don't need any scroll in the body when i do that using only css when minimize my screen scroll never show and i try it on 800*1200 not shown too

Comment: set the div to position fixed, top, left, right and bottom to 0 and overflow auto. For body and html you set overflow hidden.

Comment: Try it but not work fine here the project   http://jsfiddle.net/ASSua/

Comment: No sorry My Mistake its worked now fine thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

All you are talking about is responsive web design.

[image]

For the below HTML division:

```
<div id="container">
<!-- contents goes here -->
</div>
```

Using media queries, you can do this easily.
First add the below line to your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
```

For high resolution add the below code to  css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    #container {
        width: 1200px;
    }
}
```

Then for low resolution add the below code to  css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #container {
        width: 750px;
    }
}
```

[Responsive Web Design Guidelines and Tutorials](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/)

Hope this will helps you.

Cheers!!!